# How to handle memory leak in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a structure

```
struct Pkt_G
    {
        public long t1;
        public int t2;
        public float iv, delta, theta, vega, gamma, iv_vwap, vanna, charm, speed, zomma, color, volga, veta, tgr, tv, dtr;
        public float b1, a1, m1, Id1, id2
    }
```

I have created a dictionary of this structure inside a main class

```
internal static Dictionary<int, Pkt_G> allInst;
```

Getting data from network , then enqueue it into a queue, dequeue this queue from another thread, then parsing data and storing it into this structure object then assigning object into this **allInst** dictionary. After filling this I'm writing back this structure data into a 'raw' file by using BinaryWriter.

```
private static void AppendData(string filename, int len,  byte[] lotsOfData) //called from WriteOwnData(..) 
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
    {
        bw.Write(lotsOfData,0,len);
    }
    //lotsOfData = null;
}
void WriteOwnData(int token) //This called after assigning dictionary by latest pkt_g object
{
    try
    {
        if (!counterInit) { own_counter = GetCounter("BINARY"); counterInit = true; own_counter--; }
        int len= Marshal.SizeOf(Program.allInst[token]);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Program.allInst[token], h.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false);
        if (own_fileSize > 1024 * 1024 * 10) own_fileSize = 0;
        if (own_fileSize == 0)
        {
            own_counter++;
            BinaryWriter bwThis = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("BINARY\\" + hostPort + "_" + own_counter + ".raw", FileMode.Create));
            bwThis.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("File_Dumping:" + hostPort + "_" + own_counter);
        }
        AppendData("BINARY\\" + hostPort + "_" + own_counter + ".raw", len, buffer);                    
        own_fileSize+=len;
        //buffer = null;
        //h.Free();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex); ;
    }
}
```

that above Code doing perfect work, I am abled to parse back this data quite easily , but the major issue is that **memory leak** when I run my application memory uses continuously increasing on task manager and getting crashed after 1 to 2 hours. Any way to fix it? I have tried too many way to solve this problem, but failed to managed high memory consumption. I am requesting please give me a proper solution or any correction in my code.
Thank you..

Comment: I don't really follow your situation. Am I right in thinking that you're adding loads of things to `allInst`, but never removing anything?

Comment: No there is only this structure data of almost 1000 data points

Comment: I tried just returned back from `WriteOwnData(int token)`  function, that time I don't see high uses of memory.

Comment: Have you tried [profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage) to see if you can find what objects are staying in memory? I notice you've commented out `h.Free()` which seems odd as the documentation on [`GCHandle.Alloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.alloc) explicitly states the `GCHandle` it returns must be released with `Free` when it is no longer needed.

Comment: I just figured out that only this portion what I have written above causing the memory leak, If you will suggest some improvement in this or any other way to write structure data into binary bytes that I can try, and may help in my case.

Comment: As @JoshuaRobinson stated, why did you comment out  `h.Free();`?

Comment: I supposed might be 'h' obj may causing memory leaks, then I forcefully free it, but it does nothing.